# Basic file IO in C

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

I am working through the excellent The C Programming Language at the moment, and have got stuck while trying to open and read a file.  The program compiles, but seg faults on execution:

```
$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("/home/c-sandbox/index.html", "r");
  fprintf(fp, "Testing...\n");
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Note that the path points to a real file containing the string "hello, world".

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: I believe there's a problem opening your file. Try checking (fp == NULL) before you proceed to print anything.

Comment: Great, thanks ScarletAmaranth I'll try that when I get home - I was doing this during my lunch break

Comment: Just a thought, if you're trying to get into c, it's rather important not to make any assumptions and not to expect c to do anything for you, including warning you about what you're doing is probably not what you want. It believes you pretty blindly. That basically means that if your dynamic memory allocation fails, c believes that that's the way you wanted it and proceeds to dereference whatever data just happens to be at the location your pointer points to, and more often than not, this will lead to seg-fault since the odds of the area of memory actually belonging to you  are pretty low.

Comment: If the goal is to open and read a file, why are you writing to it? `fprintf()` is an output function, and you're trying to pass output *into* the file. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also note that the declaration of `main` is old style and not allowed anymore, it should be `int main(void)` for a `main` using no arguments and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` if arguments are used. Way back, when K&R were young, C had an 'implicit int' assumption, so when no type was specified it was assumed to be `int`. Many compilers still support it for backwards compatibility, but you should always explicitly declare the types. And you should `return` the exit-code at the end of `main` (omitting the return is an implicit `return 0;` in C99, but it's good form to explicitly return).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You opened the file for reading only, and are attempting to write to it.

Use `"a"` if you want to append to the end of the existing file.

**Edit:** As others have noted, you're also not checking to see if the file was opened. `fopen` will return `NULL` if it fails and set the global variable `errno` to a value that indicates why it failed. You can get a human-readable explanation using `strerror(errno)`

```
if( fp == NULL ) {
    printf( "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Make sure `fp` is not NULL before trying to write to it. For example:

   ```
   if(fp == NULL)
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file\n");
       return EXIT_FAILURE; // defined in stdlib.h
   }
   ```
2. You need to open the file with something other than `"r"`, which only allows file reading. Read the [man page for `fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html) to find out which mode would work the best for you. Example:

   - `"w"` - Truncate to zero length or create file for writing.
   - `"a"` - Append; open or create file for writing at end-of-file.

Comment: "Cannot open file" is the canonical example of a *bad* error message.  Use strerror or perror and let the system tell you why it cannot open the file, and include the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening it in readonly mode! Need to use `w` or `a` for writing/appending to the file :)

```
fopen("/home/c-sandbox/index.html", "w");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check that `fopen` does not return `NULL`.  I suspect it is returning `NULL` and either the `fprintf` and/or `fclose` calls are getting messed up.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    main()
    {
      FILE *fp;

      fp=fopen("/home/c-sandbox/index.html", "r");  
      if(!fp)
      { 
         perror ("The following error occurred");
         return ;
      }

      fgets(line,len,fp);
      printf("%s",line);
      fclose(fp);

     fp=fopen("/home/c-sandbox/index.html", "a");
     if(!fp)
     { 
         perror ("The following error occurred");
         return ;
     }
     fprintf(fp, "Testing...\n");
     fclose(fp)


    }
```

for reading "hello, world" string present in file.
after reading write to the same file "Testing..."